# How to integrate a SpringSource dm Server into another OSGi-based application server?

Tags: osgi, springsource, spring-dm

I would really like to use SpringSource dm Server, but our customer requires us to run our apps on their application server (Websphere). Is there a way to integrate SpringSource dm Server with other application servers? At least dm Server is build on OSGi, and many other application servers (including Websphere) are based on OSGi as well. Is it possible to run a SpringSource dm Server as a websphere component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpringSource dm Server is based on the Eclipse Equinox OSGi framework (and should not be confused with the Spring DM technology, included in dm Server, which can run on Equinox, Apache Felix, and Knopflerfish).

However, embedding dm Server in another application server, such as WebSphere Application Server, based on Equinox would be a non-trivial piece of work. It would be necessary to get both products to use the same version of Equinox, which they currently do not, then modify dm Server to support embedding in the server (e.g. to integrate with the host server's application invocation mechanism, thread pools, and class loading scheme).

If you think this support is important, please [raise a requirement](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/PLATFORM) (which requires a simple registration) against dm Server.

Answer (score 1):

Spring DM is deployed on a Knoplerfish OSGi implementation.

Websphere is deployed on an Equinox OSGi implmentation.

So the question becomes - are the two interchangeable? They both support R4, so I would say, yes, they are.

The next question would be to check dependencies, particularly with respect to things like HttpServices.

I would say this would be ok, but I think the final proof would be try deploying it. Easiest would be to drop the bundles into a Websphere deployment. You'll need your bundles and whatever spring bundles you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that this is really the case ...

see the following link for this: http://apsblog.burtongroup.com/2008/11/websphere-7-osgi.html

But it seems on the other side, that the trend is clear ... there will  be a time when OSGI based application can be deployed on Java EE application servers

Answer (score 0):

I'm also interested in this topic.  Another way of looking at this problem is that you want an application depoyable in both Spring dm server and a traditional app server (Websphere, weblogic, JBoss, ...).

The OSGi containers are embeddable inside non-OSGi applications, so it is theoretically possible to deploy an app to both Spring dm server and the same app + OSGi container to a traditional app server.

Now, as usual, the devil's in the details, including such topics of web development and bridging servlets between the outer app server and the OSGi container.